# How to change animations on one screen View by timer

Tags: ios, swift

I have several animations that I need to change to one timer on a viev. There are 2 buttons. Start and Stop and 2 Label (total time and time of animation). When you press the start, the animation starts and the timer is counted, then after 30 seconds the animation changes and so on. And when you click stop, the animation and time stop.

An example on this video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ey8lGmA1icPlojTMQlF3Auosd2IdEKSs

Comment: What library are you using for animations?

Comment: @AakashDave I use the lottie library

Comment: Here is the source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XEaaqwNeIfhIGdhq715ATUVQo3hIx8Av

Comment: Great, You need to keep the track of the animations, with `isAnimating` property of Lottie and `stop()` animation once it's complete. And then re-assign new one and run that in the completion block

Comment: @AakashDave I need the animation to vary by timer.

Comment: Irrespective of the animation, is your timer working perfectly

Comment: @AakashDave Nothing works for me except animation. I need to implement the function to change the animation on the main screen on a timer

Comment: Can you show the code for your timer